# How to sort a FacetGrid legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

In the image below, how do I sort the legend to show 'No' above 'Yes'? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col='sex', hue='smoker', col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.scatter, 'total_bill', 'tip', alpha=.7)
g.axes[-1].legend() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the `'smoker'` columns as categorical with [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# set smoker as categorical and ordered
df.smoker = pd.Categorical(df.smoker, categories=['No', 'Yes'], ordered=True)

# plot
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='sex', hue='smoker', height=5, col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.scatter, 'total_bill', 'tip', alpha=.7)
g.axes[-1].legend() 
plt.show()
```

[image]